# Badge icons partially hidden on some sites with the new design

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, profile-page, top-bar

On three sites with the new theme, [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com), [Super User](https://superuser.com) and [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com), the badge icons displayed in the user's profile summary in the top bar are partially covered by the numbers. I reported this [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/18126/606366) already but user [Josh](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/478436/josh) mentioned it's a cross-site problem. (Others posted bug reports on [Meta Server Fault](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/9356/visual-bug-with-displaing-badges) and [Meta Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/q/13258/442468).)

[image]

[image]

[image]

The problem happens only on the main site, not on the child metas, and seems to be browser-independent. It seems to be caused by the `width: 6px` rule for the badge classes:

[image] [image]

As mentioned by user [N0rbert](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/66509/n0rbert), other places are affected as well, e.g. the profile page:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been addressed and should go out after the next build. It's a little late in our day, so probably tomorrow sometime. Thanks for pointing this out!